# How to detect when the Background of a NavigationControl is clicked?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Navigation Control with a Combobox in front of it:
[image: Picture]

If a user clicks on the *background* of the NavControl (the teal part), NavControl gets focus and moves in front of the Combobox, making the Combobox unclickable until NavControl loses focus.

This sub fixes the problem, but it also triggers when any of NavControl's tabs on the left are clicked:

```
Private Sub NavControl_GotFocus()
    cbxSearch.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Is there a property of NavControl that can determine when its background was clicked vs. a tab? Something like...

```
Private Sub NavControl_GotFocus()
    'if navcontrol.tabclicked = "" then
        cbxSearch.SetFocus
    'end if
End Sub
```

Comment: Apparently there is, never used it. Try code. What happens?

Comment: What's the name of the property? I tried using .TabIndex, but it always returns 0. Experimenting with others now...

Comment: I've found a solution, but it's kinda gross..  By stretching the label of the combobox (the magnifying glass) to completely cover NavControl's background area, clicking that area now redirects to the combobox - no extra code required.

Comment: It's GotFocus event, as you show in your narrative.